# text-based C++ terminal GUI library

Tags: c++, text, formatting, window, terminal

I'm looking for a way in which I can align/format text output to the terminal window in C++, independent of the terminal window's size (I'm not looking to use iomanip with setw() or whatever). There is a library out there that allows for this, it begins with "n" I think, but I can't for the life of my find it. Honestly, I have thoroughly searched google, wikipedia etc and I just can't find it without knowing the name of it.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for the [Gnu ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) libary.